# Kill process and release memory in c++

Tags: c++, window

I have a service that it creates a process and then frees its memory.
I use createprocess() function and then close handle of process and thread,
this is my code:

```
        if (CreateProcessA(NULL,
                           zAppName,//{ pointer to command line string }
                           NULL,     //{ pointer to process security attributes }
                           NULL,     //{ pointer to thread security attributes }
                           TRUE,     //{ handle inheritance flag }
                           0,
                           NULL,     //{ pointer to new environment  block }
                           NULL,     //{ pointer to current directory name }
                           &StartupInfo,    //{ pointer to STARTUPINFO }
                           &ProcessInfo))
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(ProcessInfo.hProcess,WaitMiliSec);
        GetExitCodeProcess(ProcessInfo.hProcess, &Result);

        CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hThread);    

        CloseHandle(hRead);
        CloseHandle(hWrite);
        return (Result);
    }
```

But after closehandle() function, hProcess and hThread still have value!!!
and each time my service runs this code the memory increases and doesn't decrease!!!Is this a memory leak?
what should I do?

Comment: From the fact that handles still have their value does not mean that the process is still alive.

Comment: but what about memory? when the process release it!?(@marom)

Comment: Do you have a reason to believe some memory is not freed? Just some int values in your own program mean nothing.

Comment: yes, after i created process the memory went up , I saw in taskmanager , and after i closed the handle and the function ended, the memory didn't free(@ deviantfan)

Comment: How long is WaitMiliSec and are you certain it is long enough for the process to terminate?

Comment: @user4581301 : i set it to  _INFINITE_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the process is loaded into the memory following elements are loaded :
 1.code
 2.memory
 2.PCB
 4.Data etc.
When you close handles only some part of heap (assuming that you are using malloc to create handlers) is freed. So rest of elements still remains into the process stack. So you can't guarantee that memory is not freed.
yes hProcess and hThread might have some values that can create confusion. But these pointers hProcess and hThread will be called as "dangling pointers". So it is a good practice to assign a null value to the pointers after de-allocation.

Comment: The rest of elements remain into stack?Is this a memory leak?

Comment: No actually rest elements will be unloaded when the process terminates finally. But if you do not close the handlers, that will create memory leak (since handlers are allocated from heap).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @userNishant .I close the handles, but each time my service run this code i see in task manager that the memory increase!!! Are the rest of elements unload when main process (I mean my service) terminate?

Comment: Actually when each time you load the main process, process elements will be loaded too and when process terminates Operating System will de-allocate the resources assigned to main process.

Comment: So have you any idea that why the memory shown in task manager increase when I create process and don't decrease!?If i run this code 10 times the memory increase 10 times too!!!:(

Comment: are you running the same process repeatedly? If yes then each time process will be treated as separate and assigned a process Id to it. so each process will have its own elements that will be the cause of increased memory in task manager. You can refer to http://www.cs.kent.edu/~farrell/osf03/lectures/ch4-1.pdf & http://www.cs.kent.edu/~farrell/osf03/lectures/ch4-1.pdf for more details.

Comment: No , i run this code in a windows service, every one hour run this code in my service, and the memory of my service increase,

Comment: If you are creating a child process from parent you must wait till the child finishes. It might give you some clue : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/23/192531.aspx

Comment: I check it, I saw that the child process operation set to createfile and then closefile in procmon.exe, is this mean that child process finished!?i run only a command in child process and set waitforsingleobject to  INFINITE for it,

Comment: see this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/805232/Windows-Getting-callback-on-child-process-exit-in